# XmlMassUpdate Multiple Values (MSBuild Community Tasks)

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, msbuildcommunitytasks

Say you have a config file with the following settings:

```
<someNode>
    <node>value A</node>
    <node>value B</node>
    <node>value C</node>     
</someNode>
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get XmlMassUpdate to inject the following:

```
<someNode>
    <node>value 1</node>
    <node>value 2</node>
    <node>value 3</node>     
</someNode>
```

The result looks like this:

```
<someNode>
    <node>value 1</node>
    <node>value B</node>
    <node>value C</node>  
</someNode>
```

What I'm shooting for is:

```
<someNode>
    <node>value A</node>
    <node>value B</node>
    <node>value C</node>
    <node>value 1</node>
    <node>value 2</node>
    <node>value 3</node>    
</someNode>
```

EDIT: I found a temporary solution (see below)... still interested in something better, though.

```
<someNode>
    <node xmu:key="id" id="1">value A</node>
    <node xmu:key="id" id="2">value B</node>
    <node xmu:key="id" id="3">value C</node>
</someNode>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to apply a unique attribute to the element and use that as the xmu:key (see EDIT above).

Answer (score 2):

Get community tasks code.
Replace:

```
if (keyAttribute == null)
{
                xpath = nodeToFind.Name;
}
```

With:

```
if (keyAttribute == null)
            {
                xpath = nodeToFind.Name;
                if (nodeToFind.ChildNodes.Count == 1 && nodeToFind.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    xpath = string.Format("{0}[{1}='{2}']/{1}", parentNode.LocalName, nodeToFind.LocalName,
                                          nodeToFind.InnerText, nodeToFind.LocalName);
                    parentNode = parentNode.ParentNode;
                }
            }
```

In method :
`private XmlNode locateTargetNode(XmlNode parentNode, XmlNode nodeToFind, XmlAttribute keyAttribute)`

Rebuild.
You're done :)